# Splitting nested column to multiple columns UNIX

Tags: unix, awk

I have a tab delimited data frame with a final column containing nested information that is '|' delimited. Note that all rows maintain this nested parenthetical structure preceded by 'REP='

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ID1     text    text    text...REP=(info1|info2|info3)
ID2     text    text    text...REP=(info1|info2|info3)
```

I would like to process this last column such that all info inside the parenthetical is a new column:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4   newcol    newcol2    newcol3
ID1     text    text    text   info1     info2      info3
ID2     text    text    text   info1     info2      info3
```

I would think that an AWK command would be useful but am having trouble structuring this appropriately. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are those dots before REP really there, or does that represent more columns?

Comment: the ... represent additional text in col4 that occurs prior to 'REP='

Comment: Is there a tab before "REP"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perl` one liner, doesn't modify the header though

```
$ cat ip.txt 
col1    col2    col3    col4
ID1     text    text    text REP=(info1|info2|info3)
ID2     text    text    text REP=(info1|info2|info3)

$ perl -pe 's/\s*REP=\(([^)]+)\)/"\t".$1=~tr#|#\t#r/e' ip.txt
col1    col2    col3    col4
ID1     text    text    text    info1   info2   info3
ID2     text    text    text    info1   info2   info3
```

- `\s*REP=\(([^)]+)\)` zero or more whitespaces, followed by `REP(` followed by capture group to extract characters other than `)` and finally a `)`
- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `$1=~tr#|#\t#r` change `|` to tabs from the captured group, which is then concatenated to string containing a tab

Comment: When I try to run this code I am getting an error as follows --
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s/\|/\t/gr"
syntax error at -e line 1, near "s/\|/\t/gr "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==1{nh=NF; header=$0; next} 
                        {v=$NF; 
                         sub(/.*REP=/,"",v);
                         sub(/\.\.\.REP=.*/,"",$NF); 
                         gsub(/[()]/,"",v); 
                         n=split(v,vs,"|"); 
                         for(i=1;i<=n;i++) $(NF+i)=vs[i]} 
                   NR==2{printf "%s", header; 
                         for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s", OFS "col"(nh+i); 
                         print ""}1' file | column -t

col1  col2  col3  col4  col5   col6   col7
ID1   text  text  text  info1  info2  info3
ID2   text  text  text  info1  info2  info3
```

Comment: don't be in a rush to accept the answer; upvote is fine, perhaps there will be better solution if you wait little longer.  I do these as speed programming exercise without much thought.

Comment: Not a fan of the indentation style, but this is just how I implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

This does leave a tab at the end, but that can be fixed with an extra gsub.

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $0,"col4\tnewcol\tnewcol2\tnewcol3")} NR>1 {gsub(/...REP=\(|\||\)/, "\t");print}' input.txt
```

Comment: You only need to update the header on the first line, not every line: `awk 'NR==1 {print $0, "\tnewcol1..."} NR>1 {gsub(/REP .../...); print}'`